# Get App Id before publish them?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I get the `App Id` before publish them ? the id will be used in rate button?

Please find the below code:

```
public void RateGame(){
     #if UNITY_ANDROID
         Application.OpenURL("market://details?id=APP_ID");
     #elif UNITY_IPHONE
         Application.OpenURL("itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID");
     #endif
  }
```

the real **App Id** will be inserted on `APP_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For iOS:**

You can find the `AppID` once you create your Project in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), you find this on the first page.

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Art/4-NewApp_2x.png))</sub>

So you can change your code and then upload the app.